# CSS grid doubling it's size and breaking on Safari and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, css-grid

I'm working on a **website layout, which relies heavily on css grid**. I'm often coding using codepen. **The website looks absolutely hideous on Safari and Chrome.** Grid somehow doubles in size, but content doesn't and centers itself. I've read about Safari not liking "width: 100%;" in style of an img element, but that didn't help as well. The website looks fine on Mozilla. Advice?

Here are the screenshots:

**Safari:**

[Safari Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4KmL.jpg)

[Safari Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfwAT.png)

**Mozilla:**

[Firefox Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smUuA.jpg)

[Firefox Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjg02.jpg)

Chrome looks exactly the same as Safari.

codepen and code:
**[codepen link]**(https://codepen.io/mmotlaw/full/OJbGYbL) .

**CSS**

```
html, body, .grid-container { 
    height: 100%; 
    margin: 0;  
    font-family: 'Open Sans', 
    sans-serif;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 1.5fr 1fr 1fr 1.5fr 0.2fr;
    grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 1.4fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
        "navbar navbar navbar navbar navbar navbar"
        "b1 fullpage fullpage fullpage fullpage b2"
        "b1 fullpage fullpage fullpage fullpage b2"
        "b1 fullpage fullpage fullpage fullpage b2"
        "b1 fullpage fullpage fullpage fullpage b2";
}

.navbar {
    grid-area: navbar;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    /*background-color: rgba(121, 124, 133, 0.9);*/
    /*background-color: rgba(3, 201, 105, 0.93);
    brazik "cegiel"
    background-color: #9b7970;
    background: rgb(155,121,112);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(155,121,112,1) 0%, rgba(139,79,57,1) 100%); */
    height: 0.5fr;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.pasek {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.pasek ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.pasek ul::after {
    /*ma byc fajniutkie podkreslenie! */
}

.pasek li {
    flex: auto;
    /*
    text-shadow: .03em .04em black;*/
}

.pasek i {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link {
    display: inline-block;
    color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: black;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    //transition: width .3s;
}

.b2 {
    grid-area: b2;/*
    background-color: #97b2cf;
    background: /*rgba(45, 228, 139, 0.4);linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(151,178,207,1) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%); */
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(131, 129, 128, 0.66) 0%, rgba(226, 232, 237, 0.7) 100%);
}

.szklo {

}

.b1 { 
    grid-area: b1;
    /*
    background-color: #7cc7d9;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(151,178,207,1) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%); */
    /*background-color: rgba(121, 124, 133, 0.7);*/
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(131, 129, 128, 0.66) 0%, rgba(226, 232, 237, 0.7) 100%);
}

.fullpage { 
    grid-area: fullpage;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hide;
    background: white;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3));
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 8px #888888;
}

/* For presentation only, no need to copy the code below */
.grid-container * {
    position: relative;
}

h1{
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: arial,helvetica;
    color: #fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.intro p{
    color: #fff;
}

/* Centered texts in each section
* --------------------------------------- */
.section{
    text-align:center;
}



/* Defining each section background and styles
* --------------------------------------- */
#section0{
    /*background-image: url(kurwa2.jpg);*/
    background:linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484606075493-62da7cd65654?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D');
    background-size: cover;
}

#section2{
}

#section1{
}

#section3 {
    background-color: red;
}

#sek1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
}

#sek2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#sek3 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#sek4 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#section0 h1 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 10rem;
    /*
    mix-blend-mode: difference;*/
    text-shadow: .05em .05em black;
}

.grid-container-s1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "zdj zdj zdj tekst tekst"
    "zdj zdj zdj tekst tekst"
    "zdj zdj zdj tekst tekst"
    "zdj zdj zdj tekst tekst";
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.zdj { 
    grid-area: zdj;
}

.tekst { 
    grid-area: tekst; 
}

.grid-container-s2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "tekst2 tekst2 zdj2 zdj2 zdj2 zdj2"
    "tekst2 tekst2 zdj2 zdj2 zdj2 zdj2"
    "tekst2 tekst2 zdj2 zdj2 zdj2 zdj2"
    "tekst2 tekst2 zdj2 zdj2 zdj2 zdj2";
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.zdj2 { 
    grid-area: zdj2;  
}

.tekst2 { 
    grid-area: tekst2;
}

.grid-container-s3 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
    "Akt Akt Akt Akt Akt Akt"
    "posty posty posty posty posty posty"
    "posty posty posty posty posty posty"
    "posty posty posty posty posty posty";
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

.Akt { 
    grid-area: Akt; 
}

.posty { 
    grid-area: posty; 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
```

}

```
.post{
    margin: 1.5rem;
    max-width: 80%;
    max-height: 5rem;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 5px 0px 12px 2px #000000;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.post p {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodePen - wersja kolorowa</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl" dir="ltr">
    <head>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/jpg" href="../zdj/favicon.ico">
        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.7/fullpage.min.css" integrity="sha512-B86EZhfnYXgpK3oDeyTEHuygfIHNoyaT9QiOKzHRyKi75wnz64KGzEtiOuk2wFIvND5w9t7RjFm2kz6fgyC9OQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <!-- JS/czcionki  -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/3.0.7/fullpage.min.js" integrity="sha512-XSVy+t/Br5mj9rOtn3BlyQv3jxpMfagH8gEa/QrhZQnzrBEwcXuC+M36LLj3nJUIXQKjVQ6KQmpnnNMYnu5Gyw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="../js/aos.js"></script>
        <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js" integrity="sha512-FzESM/E7XJBqcJyrXa08gRcpp5rDHO661C0L3vH4NsZfUWUsjN4+t6Lg8h+e8TMR2aYijIrcT+CPGq7tSugRzA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <title>Housing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fullpge">
            <div class="section " id="section0">
            <h1 data-aos="fade-down">Housing</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="section" id="section1">
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <ul class="pasek">
                        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#section0"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Text</a></li>
                        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#sek1"><i class="fas fa-door-closed"></i>Text</a></li>
                        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#sek2"><i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>About</a></li>
                        <li><a class="cool-link" href="#sek3"><i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="b2"></div>
                <div class="b1"></div>
                <div class="fullpage">
                    <section id="sek1">
                        <div class="grid-container-s1">
                            <div class="zdj" style="text-align: justify; padding: 5px;">
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513584684374-8bab748fbf90?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1046&q=80" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;">
                            </div>
                            <div class="tekst" style="text-align: justify; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.4rem;">
                                <h2>Some text</h2>
                                <p>As a <b>filler!</b></p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <section id="sek2">
                        <div class="grid-container-s2">
                            <div class="zdj2">
                                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494526585095-c41746248156?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" alt="" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto;"></img>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tekst2" style="text-align: center; padding: 5px; font-size: 1.4rem;">
                              <h2>Sample text</h2>
                              <p>As a <b>filler</b></p>
                              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<!-- partial -->
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'll be grateful for any help!

Cheers,
Maciej

Comment: Not sure why this happens, but try going with px / min-content / auto for the row-heights of the container.

Comment: Thank you! It helped with the navbar. I found the fix to those nasty sections too. It turns out it wasn't about the grid - the section had height: 100%; parameter. Changed it to height: auto; and it works fine now

Comment: Well done, no need for a height on that anyways. If you wanna read up on that, there are plenty of posts on the height issue on Safari: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=safari+height+100%25 - it might come in handy one day. And if you dont mind me saying: Get familiar with the stackoverflow code editor, its useful to get quick answers around here :)

Comment: Thanks! I will, much appreciated :D